# Insert array values into random positions of another array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]
var b = ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"]
```

I want to insert b array values into random positions of a. Expected output should be:

```
var c = ["Banana", "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Orange", "Mango"]
```

Here, b-array values are inserted into a, but the value sequence of a-array is not hampered. How can I do that using Javascript?

```
"Saab" → "Volvo" → "BMW"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.splice()` to insert each item in array `b` into `a`. The position is simply a random value between `0` and `a.length - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeatedly pop values from `b` and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) them into `a` at random positions:

```js
while (b.length) {
    a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (a.length + 1)), 0, b.pop());
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! And your explanation is very clear. Thanks for taking the time to write this up.